# SSIS/Microsoft Connector for Oracle ORA-01861

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis

I am having trouble with an SSIS package that pulls data from Oracle using the Microsoft Connector for *Oracle v1.2*.

For one particular query inside of a Data Flow I am using a SQL command that queries a view in Oracle. That view uses other views and packages and functions to return the data. The query on the Oracle side works fine. However when I attempt to run it on the SQL Server side I receive "ORA-01861 literal does not match format string" with a reference to the line number of the offending package on the Oracle side.

While researching I determined that the problem is with this line of code in Oracle provided by a third party vendor.

```
 TO_DATE(sysdate,get_date_format) )
```

I am unable to change this code and I am wondering if I can somehow override this on the SSIS side. In *Visual Studio 2022* I can parse the query without issue. But when I attempt to even "preview" the data I receive the *ORA-01861* error. So this appears to be an issue with the Microsoft Connector for Oracle driver as we have an older SQL instance with the older ODBC drivers for Oracle that do not error.

Again, I cannot change the code on the Oracle side. Perhaps I could wrap the view in Oracle with *to_char* or some other function that make the data for friendly to SSIS. Or perhaps SSIS provides a way to circumvent this issue altogether.

Comment: Check the session value of NLS_DATE_FORMAT for your SSIS connection, and/or determine what format `get_date_format` is returning and where it is derived from. The line of code you provided is pretty pointless, since `sysdate` is *already* returning a `DATE` datatype; not sure how it even compiles since `to_date` would expect a character/text type, but it is what it is.

Comment: The date format being returned from that Oracle function is DD/MM/YYYY. Is there a way to force SSIS to recognize that? Edit: I tried the same process with the Microsoft ODBC drivers for Oracle and received the same error.

Comment: I doubt this is a driver issue. This feels like the PL/SQL code is using an explicit format string, while `sysdate` returns a default format, based on the session value of the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter. You will need to alter the SSIS session in Oracle to set `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to whatever the code is expecting (the return value of `get_date_format`). I'm not familiar with SSIS so not sure how to tell you to do that specifically. The SQL would be something like `alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY'`.

Comment: Can you skip the column when selecting in ssis and generate it on sql server side? Does that still crash cause oracle still evaluates the code?

Comment: I am fairly certain I need to do this somewhere on the SSIS side before calling the query in Oracle. alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY' ... I am not sure how to do that though since the SQL Command box in the Data Path can only accept a single query block. I also came across this which explains that there are changes to the newer ODBC drivers (which I tested and confirmed do not set the session value) and which also probably apply to the Microsoft Connector for Oracle drivers as well. I do not have this issue on older SQL Server running the older ODBC drivers.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/setting-the-date-format-on-connection?view=sql-server-ver16